# How to delete all files in root of File system with Delete Activity of Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have on-prem file System Data set with pathpath "Z:\ProjectX"
It has contains files like Z:\ProjectX\myfile1.json

I would like to delete all json files in "Z:\ProjectX".
I wonder how to do? What value should be set to Folder?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In source settings, select the File path type as Wildcard file path and provide the Wildcard file name as ‘*.json’ to delete all the files of type JSON.

[image]